# is this correct BEM?

Tags: html, bem

I am not sure what to do with the "about-text_container" div.  I need it to put a flexbox around the text so I can center it.  What should I do in this situation?  Create a new block?

```
<!--ABOUT SECTION-->
        <section class="about-section">
            <div class="about-section__container">
                **<div class="about-section__text">**
                    <div class="about-text__container">
                        <h1 class="about-title">Our Story</h1>
                        <em>
                            <h3 class="about-subtitle">&ldquo;Changing people's lives through fitness&ldquo;</h3>
                        </em>
                        <p class="about-description">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate
                            aperiam
                            qui culpa nam magni vel, quasi nobis vitae voluptates, sed quisquam labore neque dolorum fuga,
                            dignissimos soluta nisi alias officia unde. Ut perspiciatis repellendus nisi!</p>
                        <a href="#" class="about-section__button btn-small">Learn More</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="about-section__pictures">
                    <img src="/img/mma2.jpg" alt="about-img1" class="img1">
                    <img src="/img/yoga2.jpg" alt="about-img2" class="img2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Modifier `.about-text__container` without block `.about-text` imo is not correct. Add `display: flex;` in `.about-section__text`

Answer (score 0):

I renamed the classes, Check this out:

```html
<section class="about">
  <div class="about-wrapper">
    <div class="about__heading">
      <div class="about__heading-wrapper">
        <h1 class="about__title">Our Story</h1>
        <em>
          <h3 class="about__subtitle">
            &ldquo;Changing people's lives through fitness&ldquo;
          </h3>
        </em>
        <p class="about__description">
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate
          aperiam qui culpa nam magni vel, quasi nobis vitae voluptates, sed
          quisquam labore neque dolorum fuga, dignissimos soluta nisi alias
          officia unde. Ut perspiciatis repellendus nisi!
        </p>
        <a href="#" class="about__button about__button--small">Learn More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="about__images">
      <img src="/img/mma2.jpg" alt="about-img1" class="about__images--first" />
      <img src="/img/yoga2.jpg" alt="about-img2" class="about__images--second" />
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

For Centralizing your heading, it is better to style `about__heading-wrapper`

```
.about__heading-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```